# JMH giving <not counted> values when profiling with perf

Tags: java, profiling, perf, jmh

I would like to run benchmarks in Java and get hardware counters.
I wanted to use JMH to do so, since it seems like a mature tool. It also has options to hook profiles (for instance the perf tool, which is also mature).
My problem is that, when running my benchmarks with `java -jar benchmarks.jar -prof perf`, all counters display the value `<not counted>`.

```
Perf stats:
--------------------------------------------------

     <not counted>      task-clock
     <not counted>      context-switches
     <not counted>      cpu-migrations
     <not counted>      page-faults
     <not counted>      cycles
     <not counted>      instructions
     <not counted>      branches
     <not counted>      branch-misses
     <not counted>      L1-dcache-loads
     <not counted>      L1-dcache-load-misses
     <not counted>      LLC-loads
     <not counted>      LLC-load-misses
   <not supported>      L1-icache-loads
     <not counted>      L1-icache-load-misses
     <not counted>      dTLB-loads
     <not counted>      dTLB-load-misses
     <not counted>      iTLB-loads
     <not counted>      iTLB-load-misses
   <not supported>      L1-dcache-prefetches
   <not supported>      L1-dcache-prefetch-misses

       0,379402355 seconds time elapsed
```

If I run `perf` independently, for instance by typing `perf stat sleep 5`, then I do get results:

```
Performance counter stats for 'sleep 5':

          0,588915      task-clock (msec)         #    0,000 CPUs utilized
                 1      context-switches          #    0,002 M/sec
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0,000 K/sec
                60      page-faults               #    0,102 M/sec
         1 048 769      cycles                    #    1,781 GHz
           807 919      instructions              #    0,77  insn per cycle
           159 210      branches                  #  270,345 M/sec
             7 325      branch-misses             #    4,60% of all branches

       5,001500262 seconds time elapsed
```

Answer (score 4):

I have found the answer, I leave it for other people who ran in a similar issue.

The calls to `perf` had the parameter `--delay 21000` which introduced a delay before starting counting. Since the benchmarks were shorter than that, counting never started.

The issue was solved by using the command `java -jar benchmarks.jar -prof perf:delay 0`. `:` is used to pass options to the profiler.

Comment: You probably want some delay to allow for JVM warmup, and for it to get out of the code that launched `perf` and back into the benchmark itself.

Comment: I agree! I used no delay here to make sure that something was indeed counted and that it was not a problem with getting data from the hardware counters.